# Wordpress Plugin Upgrade Hook Function

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I'm developing new version of my wordpress plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-send-like-button/) .

New options (`add_option()`) coming with new version. But i can't register this new options automatically.

For example there is **fgb_single** option in new version.
Where should i put `add_option('fgb_single', 'on');`  code in my plugin's file?

Answer (score 7):

The [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) is using the global `$wpdb`, make sure you have that declared before using any function like [add_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) or [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).
Also acording to the WordPress Codex, you will see no changes when you use `add_option($option, $value, $deprecated, $autoload)` if you already have a value for that option:

> Note: `add_option` uses get_option to determine whether the option already exists, and since `get_option` returns false as the default value, if you set an option to false in the database (e.g. via `update_option($option_name, false))`, then a subsequent call to `add_option` will change the value, because it will seem to `add_option` that the option does not exist.

You can use the Options API anywhere in your plugin as log as you load `$wpdb`.
Also I'd recommend using [update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) instead of [add_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) as it is able to create new options but won't return false in case an option already exists, it will simply overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The bounty is rightfully yours!